# Rails Scaffolding issue in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

rails scaffold chatroom name

rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'scaffold' (see --tasks)
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in`'

Comment: You are missing the `generate`.

Comment: Thanks @AlejandroMontilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `generate` keyword, and the datatype of the field `name`, so your command should be:

```
bin/rails generate scaffold ChatRoom name:string
```

Note the ***camelCase*** in `ChatRoom`, in this case Rails will generate ***snake_case*** names for your files, (i.e. `app/controllers/chat_rooms_controller.rb`. If you dont want this kind of names, change `ChatRoom` to `Chatroom` and you will get `app/controllers/chatrooms_controller.rb`.